# Some Qt designer palette colors won't apply on windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, colors, qt-designer, palette

As the title says, I am trying to change colors in the palette of my various panels on windows 7 and the effected areas won't change from the default color. They work just fine on my windows xp computer. Both are the same installation of Qt, one day old.

I have noticed the following roles effected:
button
base
whichever color is for groupbox header text, tooltip i belive

Is there any way to fix, or at least, work around this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this reply. This is the palette code generated by the qt visual studio plugin: [link](http://pastebin.com/M82uX1pH). Almost all palette qualities of items inside the toolbox are inherited from the base toolbox settings.